# Page load issue in Orbeon Forms 4.5 CE (Separate Deployment)

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I have a simple web application ([loadissue.war](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3401190/loadissue.war)) that uses Orbeon Forms 4.5 CE to process XForms (Separate Deployment). The web application contains a simple XHTML+XForms page (`loadissue.xhtml`) that contains both an HTML link and an XForms load link to itself. In `web.xml`, I have configured Orbeon Forms to filter url patterns matching `*.xhtml`.

The page gets rendered properly, i.e., XForms markup is transformed into HTML+CSS+JavaScript. If I click either of the links (HTML or XForms), a blank page is shown as a response (no response content) instead of the expected result, i.e., a page reload. This happens if I use the `.xhtml` file suffix with my file.

However, if I reconfigure `web.xml` and tell Orbeon Forms to filter url patterns matching `.jsp` instead of `.xhtml` everything works as expected with the `loadissue.jsp` file, in which the contained links (obviously) now point to this file.

I know that long time ago in the past Orbeon Forms accepted other file suffixes than `.jsp` in separate deployment mode and worked perfectly. So maybe I am missing a configuration option with this new version or something. I hope the linked `.war` file helps to reproduce the load issue and possibly suggest what I am doing wrong.

Comment: For reference: we are discussing this offline. It seems to be an issue of character encoding. Possibly [this commit](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/commit/b848343a5e0e1b127eda5fb85752402d5fff25e2) will help addressing that.

Comment: Did you try to run the sample web application (`loadissue.war`)? Do the links in `loadissue.xhtml` work now with the fix?

Comment: I tried this, and I do reproduce the issue. It seems that with an XHTML file, when the browser issues a conditional GET, the request reaches the Orbeon filter but then the filter chain does not reach our servlet, so the response is empty. It is as if the Tomcat default filter was handling this as a "not modified" result. I found a workaround by not propagating the "If-*" headers in that case. This should be reasonably safe as the purpose of the filter is to process dynamic pages, which means that in fact there shouldn't even be conditional GET processing for those resources.

Comment: And here is the issue I created https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1796

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I entered and created an issue for this. What I observe is in the comments above. It is unclear what is actually happening without digging more into what Tomcat does, but the workaround by filtering "If-*" headers in the filter seems to work.